# Forbid changes to plank

Tags: desktop

I want to use elementary in children education.
Its possible to lock the bar at the bottom of the screen?

Regards
Allan

Answer (score 2):

bring up slingshot and type in `plank --preferences` go to behaviour and lock the dock.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the dock(plank) at the bottom by -

- Press `Ctrl` and Right click on the dock and choose preferences

  [image]
- In the behaviour section remove the option for hiding dock.

[image]  > > > [image]

Since you asked for `bar` there is a way to turn the dock to a bar in elementary.

- In the same preferences dialogue go in behavior and select fill in alignment, also choose Start in Icon Alignment.

[image]

These settings give you a bar at the bottom which looks and works much like that of MSWindows >>

[image]

*Note- the theme in the screenshots is [capeos](https://github.com/fsvh/plank-themes)*

Comment: I do not have any preferences when I right click on the dock.

Comment: @AllanRamsby use `ctrl-rtclick`